# Получить последние значения от тэгов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Идея такова - в базе таблица

```
 id tag_id value time
  1   1      12  12:14
  2   1      12  12:15
  3   2      11  12:13
```

хочу получить по одной последней записи для всех тэгов. т.е. с id 2 и id 3

desc limit вроде не подходит, да и group by вроде нет

Comment: Рекомендую внести изменения в структуру базы. Логика говорит, что сортивку выборки нужно делать по time. Но что будет, если первая запись попадет в базу, к примеру, в 23:59:59, f следующая в 00:00:01 следующего дня? Дополнительно задействовать id? Что же, практика (судя по комментам) появления дырок у вас уже есть. Осталось дождаться практики переинициализации id (корявый переезд, или еще что). Так что, мой вам совет, замените time на timestamp.

Comment: `group by`, по моему, тут тоже прекрасно работает. Странно, что у Вас не получилось ... [Sql fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65e2c/2)

Comment: да оно timestamp

Comment: вы value не учли. и от max(id) не стоит прыгать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А id инкрементальный? Тогда можно вот так:

```
SELECT
    tv.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tag_id
        ,MAX(id) tv_id
    FROM
        tags_values tv
    GROUP BY
        tag_id
) x
INNER JOIN
    tags_values tv ON tv.id = x.tv_id
```

Если отталкиваться от времени

```
  SELECT tv.*
  FROM
    ( SELECT tag_id AS tv_tag_id,
                       MAX(f_timestamp) AS tv_timestamp
     FROM data_view tv
     WHERE f_timestamp >now() - interval '5 minutes'
     GROUP BY tag_id) x
  LEFT JOIN data_view tv ON tv.f_timestamp = x.tv_timestamp
  AND x.tv_tag_id = tv.tag_id
```

**UPDATE**

Если такой вариант не подходит, то можно воспользоваться [LATERAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html). Он есть в `PostreSQL` начиная с `9.3`

```
SELECT
    y.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tag_id
    FROM
        tags_values
    GROUP BY
        tag_id
) x,
LATERAL
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        tags_values tv
    WHERE
        tv.tag_id = x.tag_id
    ORDER BY
        tv.time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) y
```

Comment: по логике да. но бывают и разрывы (столкнулся при партицировании). так что max (time) уместнее

Comment: с небольшой поправкой все заработало

Comment: Добавил пример для `LATERAL`

Comment: он чем то лучше\хуже первоначального решения?

Comment: Первого - нет. С условием того, что выполняется условие: чем больше id тем больше время. С Вашим вариантом проблема может быть в том, что несколько изменений произошли сразу один за другим (с точностью в секунды скажем) и что тогда? У вас для одного тэга получится несколько значений. Вариант с LATERAL позволит этого избежать

Comment: ИМХО, привязка к постоянному инкременту id - плохая практика (читай мой комментарий к вопросу).

Comment: там условие на уникальность наложено. не может быть одинакового времени. вы не учли диапазон кст.

Comment: можете в чат пройти? вопрос несколько изменился, а этот править или новый создавать нет смысла http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31696/lateral

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант решения:

```
                select *
                from (
                    select *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tag_id ORDER BY id DESC)
                    from TABLENAME
                ) as foo
                where
                    rank = 1
```